# NodeJS - module.export & fileRead value return to Caller Class

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have `readmsgfile.js` file which has `module.exports` and fs.readFile function in it which reads a File and returns the data after some operation.

I would like to return the `msgBody` from `readmsgfile` class but the Caller Class A always gets "Undefined" in the line code var `respondMsg`. I tried to return the value outside of `fs.readfile` scope but did not work.

what modifications have to be done to get the `msgBody` var value from `readmsgfile` file to caller Class A

```
readmsgfile.js
--------------------
const fs = require("fs");

var msgBody;

module.exports = {
  readMSGFile: async function (filepath) {

   let path = filepath;
    var regex = /\\/g;
    const pathOfString = path.replace(regex, "/");

      fs.readFile(pathOfString, function (err, data) {
      var msgBody = Sum Operation Done! ;
      return msgBody;
    });

   return msgBody;
  },
  
};


Class A:
--------------------------
const readFile = require("../readmsgfile");

Async function(){
var respondMsg = await readFile.readMSGFile(detailsoffile);
console.log(respondMsg);
}
```

Comment: try with async keyword lowercase

Answer (score 0):

You should not mix callbacks and async functions up:

Promise way:

```js
//readmsgfile.js
module.exports = {
  readMSGFile: function (filepath) {
    // returning the Promise
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let path = filepath;
      var regex = /\\/g;
      const pathOfString = path.replace(regex, "/");
   
      fs.readFile(pathOfString, function(err, data) { // this is a callback function!
        var msgBody = Sum Operation Done! ;
        
        // here you could also check if there is a error       
        if (err) { reject(err); }

        // return msgBody;
        // You can not return from the callback so use resolve
        resolve(msgBody);
      });
    });
  }
};

//Class A:
async function myFun(){
  var respondMsg = await readFile.readMSGFile(detailsoffile);
  console.log(respondMsg);
}
```

Callback way:

```js
//readmsgfile.js
module.exports = {
  readMSGFile: function (filepath, successCallback, failureCallback) {
    let path = filepath;
    var regex = /\\/g;
    const pathOfString = path.replace(regex, "/");
   
    fs.readFile(pathOfString, function (err, data) { // this is a callback function!
      var msgBody = Sum Operation Done! ;

        // here you could also check if there is a error       
        if (err) { failureCallback(err); }

        // return msgBody;
        // You can not return from the callback so use your successCallback
        successCallback(msgBody);
    });
  }
};

//Class A:
function myFun(){
  var respondMsg = readFile.readMSGFile(detailsoffile, msgBody => {
    console.log(respondMsg);
  });
}
```